# How to go to the beginning of a specific line in python 3.x to make changes in it?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a a way to go up a line ( like a opposite \n ) or to go to the start of a specific line ( say line number = 9 )

Given below is the code I tried to create images like [fig] where I could input units of lenght and breadth

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neghh.png)

well, the out for a certain case looks like ..[fig]

```
enter the length unit as integer(not more than 20):5
enter the breadth unit as integer(not more than 20) :5

* * * * * 
*        *
*        *
*        *

* * * * *
```

you see that blank second-last line .. i have been trying to get rid of it for sometime but if i remove

```
 \n
```

i dont know a way to proceed .. so i thought if i could jump up to that line, i could solve the issue somehow..

{ i checked similar questions here and tried the suggested methods but it didn't work ( eg: goto , "\033[F" )}

ps: i am a beginner in python.

Comment: Please share actual code, not images - otherwise people cannot copy, try out and suggest fixes.

Comment: apparently, this is my first post here.. i'm sorry but i did try to add the code but its showing error .. is there a way to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some general code review. I think the unnecessary complexity of your code is part of the problem. The construct you're using in your code:

```py
def symbol():
    box()
def box():
    # Your actual code
symbol()
```

isn't doing anything useful beyond running `# Your actual code`. You can get rid of all the function definitions and just write the section I've called `# Your actual code` in each case. Also, your middle two sections run exactly the same code so don't need to be separate.

What you need to do to remove the excess newline is pass the option **`end=""`** to `print()`; this removes the default newline on the end of the print statement.

Final code, excluding the difference between the cases which are use `p-1` and `p-2`, is below.

```py
x = int(input("Enter length (≤20): "))
y = int(input("Enter height (≤20): "))

symb = "*"

if x > 20 or y > 20:
    print("error")
else:
    row = (symb + " ") * x
    print(row)
    central = (symb + (" " * (len(row) - 1)) + symb + "\n") * (y - 2)
    print(central, end="")
    print(row)
```

When run this produces (for inputs 12, 10):

```
Enter length (≤20): 12
Enter height (≤20): 10
* * * * * * * * * * * * 
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
*                       *
* * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Comment: Well...if you dont mind ... could you tell me how you added "less than or eq to symbol" to your code and also, how do i add code for a question .. ( i tried adding code but it said that mine reqd formatting but nothing i did seem to work ...)